# React + Jest + testing-library: "Please upgrade to at least react-dom@16.9.0 to remove this warning." ...but react-dom is 16.9.0 already

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests for my React app using Jest and [testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro)

My tests pass but I can't get rid of this error:

```
It looks like you're using a version of react-dom that supports the "act" function, but not an awaitable version of "act" which you will need. Please upgrade to at least react-dom@16.9.0 to remove this warning.
```

I am also seeing multiple instances of this warning:

```
Warning: An update to ConnectFunction inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */
```

Here are the imports at the top of my test suite:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

//testing-library/react
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElement, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import {
  wait
} from '@testing-library/dom';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';
```

Here's my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
  }
```

`react-dom` is already on v16.9. What am I missing?

Frustratingly, **this error seems to appear intermittently**. As I'm trying different things it will sometimes vanish entirely for a few runs of the test suite and then return.

Comment: Did you try? `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`

Comment: @LongNguyen Yes I try that periodically but no success.

Comment: Make sure your `react` and `react-dom` packages are the same versions.

Comment: @Clarity I bumped `react-dom` to 16.11 (to match `react`) and that made the "awaitable" error go away.  It seems like my question has two different problems so I'm going to split the second art into a new question. If you submit an answer for the issue you just solved I will accept it.

Comment: @Clarity I split the second part off into this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847236/react-jest-testing-library-warning-an-update-to-connectfunction-inside-a Ready to accept your answer whenever...

Comment: @Clarity Darn! I spoke too soon... Long story short: when I bumped the `react-dom` version I saw some different errors/warnings in the console but _not_ that one. So I thought it was solved. But after some additional housekeeping to quite those other warnings, the original "awaitable" error came back again. :-/

Comment: But does the message `Please upgrade to at least react-dom@16.9.0` still appear?

Comment: @Clarity Correct. It is the exact same original message, including that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of struggling with this mystery, I finally restarted my computer and the errors/warnings vanished. I don't understand why that mattered, as I had restarted the test script many times, as well as completely re-installed `node_modules` many times. My best guess is that it had something to do with transitioning from `react-test-renderer` module to the `testing-library` wrapper... but that is pure speculation.

- macOS v10.14.6
- node v11.10.1
- npm v6.7.0

Hope this saves someone else some time.